# WPF: Problem with binding values to ComboBox inside GridViewColumn

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, gridviewcolumn

My Views dataContext is bounded to a presentationModel with two observableCollections Members. In the View I have one listView which ItemSource is bound to is the first observableCollection. In one of the LilstViews column I want to present values from the second obeservable Colletion in my presentationModel. I cant figure out how to get the values from the observableCollection into my combobox. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you need to do is create a data template containing your ComboBox, in this case I have bound the ItemsSource to a DependencyProperty on the host Window. This  contains the presentation model, which has a property called ComboSource. SelectedValue has been bound, via the ListViewItem's DataContext, to a property which holds the selected value.

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="comboBoxTemplate">
        <ComboBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding 
                            Path=ModelData.ComboSource, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding 
                            Path=DataContext.Selection, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Item"
            SelectedValuePath="Id"
            />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Then you will need to reference this from the CellTemplate on the GridViewColumn

```
<GridViewColumn
    Header="Selection"
    Width="160"
    CellTemplate="{StaticResource comboBoxTemplate}"
    />
```